# gpg does not ask for passphrase on one encrypted file

Tags: encryption, gnupg, public-key-encryption

I have a test encrypted file on my computer that when I run

```
gpg(2) --verify message.txt.asc
```

I get:

```
gpg: Signature made Tue Mar  3 21:16:41 2015 PST using RSA key ID *******
gpg: Good signature from "John Doe <jdoe@email.com>"
gpg: WARNING: not a detached signature; file 'message.txt' was NOT verified!
```

And if I run

```
gpg(2) -d message.txt.asc
```

It does not prompt for the passphrase on my private key and yet still decrypts the gpg message.  The other random .gpg/.asc files I have require that I decrypt them with a passphrase and --verify does not work.

What is the deal with the original file such that --verify works and I can decrypt without a passphrase? Is there a gpg command that analyzes a given file so I can gain context as to why it is not password protected?  I thought it might be a detached signature (albeit without the default .sig extension) but there is a message in it as well.  I do not have a gpg-agent running fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out.  The file in question must have been created with just the `--sign` option and not both `--sign --encrypt`.  Based on looking at the file relative to another that was both signed and encrypted, you can see they both have signatures but the file created with only `--sign` does not have a `:encrypted data packet` and only has the literal data packet:

```
(10:35) gpg > gpg --list-packets test2.txt.enc.asc
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid
    data: [2048 bits]

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "John Doe <jdoe@email.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID ********, created 2015-02-28

:encrypted data packet:
    length: 405
    mdc_method: 2
gpg: encrypted with <a key>
:compressed packet: algo=2
:onepass_sig packet: keyid
    version 3, sigclass 0x00, digest 8, pubkey 1, last=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1463246548, name="test2.txt",
    raw data: 32 bytes
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid
    version 4, created 1463246548, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 8, begin of digest 35 d8
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2016-05-14)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID)
    data: [2045 bits]
```

Versus:

```
gpg > gpg --list-packets test2.txt.asc
:compressed packet: algo=1
:onepass_sig packet: keyid
    version 3, sigclass 0x00, digest 2, pubkey 1, last=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1463246421, name="test2.txt",
    raw data: 32 bytes
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid
    version 4, created 1463246421, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 2, begin of digest b9 a7
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2016-05-14)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID)
    data: [2047 bits]
```

Comment: If it's not encrypted, just look at it with a text editor, or even hex editor. Running `file` on it should say if it's a pgp/gpg file or not too